# Does matlab have a function which can calculate the intersections of two line in N dimension?

Tags: matlab

Does matlab have a function which can calculate the intersections of two line in N ($N\in R$)dimension?

line 1 is as follows $w_1^Tx_2=c_1$, where $w_1,x_1 \in R^N$
line 2 is as follows $w_2^Tx_2=c_2$, where $w_2,x_2 \in R^N$

Sorry, the above are hyperplanes. Since hyperplanes can be written in a concise way but lines in dimension ($N>2$) cannot, I tend to make a mistake like this.

Maybe the most concisest way to form a line is as follows, 
the line through $x_0$ in the direction $v$, $x=x_0+kv,k\in R$

I know there is a function 'polyxpoly'. But it only deal with $N=2$, right?

Thank you;)

Comment: Can't you write one yourself?

Comment: Also, how do these equations describe lines? Don't they actually describe (hyper)planes?

Comment: May I ask you why are you using MATLAB for doing this?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry about that!

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: there are all sorts of reasons someone might want to do something in MATLAB. Two obvious ones are: 1. They are familiar with it, so they prefer to work within it when possible 2. They need to do something within the context of a larger MATLAB program, and it's usually better to do so in MATLAB rather than having to muck about with a foreign function interface.

Comment: @dfeuer I meant he could do that himself and put the result on MATLAB functions, m-files, ... .

Comment: Teaching people to use tools efficiently is better than giving them any tools they think they need!

Comment: Would it be sufficient to solve this with matrices?  All you would have to do is enter the coefficients in the right way, then apply the appropriate matrix function to have matlab spit out the answer

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html). Do you have this in your version of matlab?

Comment: No. This problem is equivalent to nothing more than solving a linear system. If done in symbolic math, the appropriate function would be [`sym/linsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linsolve.html), which is a wrapper around the symbolic version of [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html).